# How to add object into yaml via bash script

Tags: bash, shell, yaml

I have around 200 values.yaml files in multiple directory which I need to correct if it is required. Loop to find file is a not a problem but how to edit/update files without yq using bash script.

So bash script need to check if values.yaml files contains array: containers if so please add object imageprefix: "" below imagename. However sometimes values.yaml in container section have already added such obeject and have to skip it, and do not duplicate.

My yaml file look like

```
service:
  path: /
  ports:
    - port: 6055

containers:
  container1:
    name: service
    org: "company:"
    imagename: thirdparty-service
    tagprefix: "-"

volumes:
- name: pod-logs
  emptyDir: {}

envMap:
  env:
    N_PERROUTE: 20
    NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG: 10
    NUM_STREAM_T
```

Output

```
service:
  path: /
  ports:
    - port: 6055

containers:
  container1:
    name: service
    org: "company:"
    imagename: thirdparty-service
    imageprefix: ""
    tagprefix: "-"
      periodSeconds: 30

volumes:
- name: pod-logs
  emptyDir: {}

envMap:
  env:
    N_PERROUTE: 20
    NUM_STREAM_THREADS_CONFIG: 10
    NUM_STREAM_T
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, even failed

Comment: Doing this without using a CLI specifically built to deal with yaml is going to be a pain in the butt. I'd probably go with `awk`, but it's going to be dicey. Can you use python?

Comment: Where does `periodSeconds: 30` come from in your expected output?

Comment: I don't use python as I don't know it :)

Comment: Where's the value for `NUM_STREAM_T` ?

Comment: NUM_STREAM_T: 5

Answer (score 1):

The `yq` utility exists for this purpose:

```
yq '.containers.container1.imagename="thirdparty-service" | .containers.container1.periodSeconds=30' input.yml
```

More syntax for less typing:

```
yq '.containers.* |= (.imagename="thirdparty-service" | .periodSeconds=30)' input.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with awk:

**script.awk**

```
/tagprefix: "-"/ {
    printf "%s\n      periodSeconds: 30\n", $0
    next
}
/imagename: thirdparty-service/ {
    printf "%s\n    imageprefix: \"\"\n", $0
    next
}
{ print }
```

- assumes your input is stored in file input.yml
- use it like this: `awk -f script.awk input.yml`
- As mentionned in the comments, a dedicated yaml library in a language such as python is more flexible.
- This solution is super specific to your yaml format.
- Ex. if you have twice the line `tagprefix: "-"`, it will add the periodSeconds line twice.  This solution does not verify the yaml hierarchy.
- But it works for the specific purpose you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Bash + sed:

```
if grep -q '^containers:' input.yml
then
sed -i '/imagename:/a \ \ \ \ imageprefix: ""' input.yml
fi
```